# Jquery resizable not working

Tags: jquery, resize

I have included all the jqueries file still i am not able to resize the sqaure div. My file is saved on the desktop and jquery-1.11.1.min.js is also present on my desktop. Why resizable function is not working...?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #square{
                width:400px;
                height:400px;
                background-color:green;
                padding:3px;
        }
    </style>    
</head>
<body>

    <div id="square"></div>

    <script>
        $("#square").resizable();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ympx4rhw/1/)

Comment: @Xenyal's version uses jQuery's ready handler (as he should). Perhaps the OP should too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i just tried your code and got 404 error on the css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

I replaced it with this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" />
```

And it's just works fine for me.

Comment: I tried with both http and https yesterday and it was not working and today it's working both with http and https lol!

Comment: @user3510922 i guess it because '/smoothness/' and not '/base/'

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and made it work on my local. I'm almost certain it's not working because you aren't loading your resources properly.

Few mistakes in your code:

1) Put `http:` before `//ajax` in your `link` and `script` tags. 
2) Your `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` file has to be in the same directory as your page for it to work (which I feel it isn't. If you haven't downloaded the source file, you can use [**jQuery's CDN here**](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js).

Comment: Your jquery-1.11.1.min.js is present in the same directory and i added http and https before //ajax still it was not working...strange it is working now, don;t know why it was not working yesterday...